# How to use python requests with scrapy?

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-shell

I am trying to use `requests` to fetch a page then pass the response object to a parser, but I ran into a problem:

```
def start_requests(self):
    yield self.parse(requests.get(url))
def parse(self, response):
  #pass
```

> builtins.AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'dont_filter'

Comment: I cannot tell from your code where `request` is defined.

Comment: i think " if not request.dont_filter and self.df.request_seen(request):" is part of error

Comment: Why are you trying to use the `requests` library instead of `scrapy.Request`s?

Comment: for some reason on some sties,requests works

Comment: Did you find any workaround?

Answer (score 3):

You first need to download the page's resopnse and then convert that string to HtmlResponse object

```
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
resp = requests.get(url)

response = HtmlResponse(url="", body=resp.text, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: hey, I have the same problem as op. i tried ur code |||||||||||

response = HtmlResponse(url="", body=requests.get(line).text, encoding='utf-8')
yield response    ||||||||

got this error """'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute 'dont_filter'"""

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is

1. get the page with python requests and save it to variable different then Scrapy response.

> r = requests.get(url)

2. replace scrapy response body with your python requests text.

> response = response.replace(body = r.text)

thats it. Now you have Scrapy response object with all data available from python requests.

Answer (score 0):

`yields` return a generator so it iterates over it before the request get's the data you can remove the yield and it should work. I have tested it with sample URL

```
def start_requests(self):
    self.parse(requests.get(url))
def parse(self, response):
    #pass
```