# How can I override ScraPy's Request and use python-requests instead?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, python-requests

I've been looking to start using [ScraPy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest) for a large web scraping project. I've been using [python-requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master) (HTTP for Humans) and [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for most of the websites I've scraped over the last 5 years.

**My reasons for wanting to use the `requests` library over `Scrapy.Request`:**

- While playing around with `Scrapy`, I've noticed the content returned to be very primitive in the sense that it's more equivalent to the raw format. Whereas, with `requests.content` and `requests.text` the output is cleaner due to how `requests` more elegantly handles content-encoding.
- I've seen [issues](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2431) with `Scrapy.Request` not returning the same content as the `requests` library.
- `requests` offers easy ways to conveniently access response headers, such as [`rel="next"`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#link-headers) links, whereas `Scrapy.Request` does not (and also converts headers to uppercase and forces the format to bytes).
- `requests` offers a convenient `response.json()` method (I know, I know, trivial, but still). It's been briefly discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2444) and has been essentially rotting since 2016.

I've seen similar questions regarding doing this on StackOverflow. The most direct request was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56230826/2962937), but it did not receive much attention and just like the other questions I found mentioning wanting to use `python-requests` with `ScraPy`, people either unknowingly assumed the OPs were talking about `Scrapy.Request` or simply ignored the point of the question and provided a `Scrapy.Request` equivalent to the OPs' requests.

The first `Scrapy` method I started looking into to see about overriding `Scrapy.Request` was [`start_requests`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests).

**No Luck**

Then I thought about seeing if someone had created a custom [`Downloader-Middleware`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html) that allowed for drop-in `python-requests` compatibility.

**No Luck**

Finally, I thought to try searching for an upstream solution, involving `Twisted`'s way of handling requests. That's the only place where I found anything close to a solution, [`txrequests`](https://pypi.org/project/txrequests/). However, there didn't seem to be a way to tie that in with `Scrapy`.

So, having done my research, here i am asking for help.

## Finally, the Question

While I know it might be ill-advisable, I'm asking how can I override `Scrapy.Request` to use `python-requests` across my entire project?

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because requests is not asynchronous. Unless you're ok with that in which case I don't see the point of using scrapy.

If you're not happy with scrapy requests you could try [aiohttp](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp) or switch to an asynchronous language like Go or Node.

Comment: `txrequests` takes care of extending the `requests` library to be async. I just don't know how or where to apply it for it be used throughout the entire project. I'm guessing it'd be in a custom `downloader-middleware`.

Comment: I've never heard of txrequests. You might want to contact the author.